# Simple JavaScript Question, returning NULL in IE but working in FireFox!

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, vb.net, ajax

I have this function *correctly* linked in an external .js file...

```
 function SubmitAge(age, UpdatePanelID, HiddenAgeID) {
  $get(HiddenAgeID).value = age;
  __doPostBack(UpdatePanelID);
 }
```

and am calling it like this from an onClick of an `a href="#"` ... `html` tag

(tags removed, please scroll right as stackoverflow has the greatest difficulty in displaying simple content, 7th display related edit, thanks stackoverflow)

```
a href="#" onclick="SubmitAge(24, 'ctl00_MainContent_arFrom_upAgeRange', 'MainContent_arFrom_HiddenAge')" runat="server" 24 /a
```

yet, i am getting this error, and its being called on the first line of the SubmitAge function (line with $get(HiddenAgeID)... etc...)

```
Error:
Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'null' is null or not an object
```

i've copied and pasted my WATCH windows in visual studio .net (vs2010 beta 2 using vb.net & c#) while the execution breaks inside teh SubmitAge .js function...

```
  age 53 Number
  UpdatePanelID "ctl00_MainContent_arTo_upAgeRange" String
  HiddenAgeID Undefined identifier Error
```

Why on earth is HiddenAgeId, clearly passed just like UpdatePanelID, is returning an "Undefined identifier Error"??? its perplexed me to the point where i have no room to move! have i missed something guys? thanks - your help or pointers is greatly appreciated.

edit: Update: turns out it works perfectly (as it should) when i load it up in FireFox, but has the resulting error in Internet Explorer, this is not a browser compatibility issue, it should *also* work in IE, but it doesn't!

Comment: You should edit your question title to something more descriptive, like "Strange null-related error in simple Ajax call to ASP.net". By the way, this is a good and interesting question, but is not exactly what I expected to see in a "simple" question ;)

Comment: Certainly it would look like it shouldn't happen from the code given. But then the ago doesn't exactly match the example HTML given, so who knows. May we have eg. a test page with the error? Incidentally you should `return false` from your click handler to stop the link being followed (and bouncing the page to the top due to `#`).

Comment: what do you mean 'ago'? the onclick correctly sends 3 arguments to the SubmitAge function, which uses all of them correctly. it works in firefox without issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so far, i've determined that this is a bug in internet explorer, it really is not expected behaviour, and it can't be by design under any condition, and i'm almost certain it's a bug. i have tried everything from rearranging js function arguments to adding dummy arguments, and restarting internet explorer, visual studio and the computer several times with no luck.

so, i've decided to put the entire functions contents directly into the onclick="(lines of code" event attribute, which means that for every single page on my website, the entire functions lines of code will have to be re printed 110 times (a good 20 to 30 KB of download for users)... this is for the time being anyway, until i have the time to find a better solution.

does anyone know if we can give the correct department's bug report team a link or a pointer to this thread so that they may at least investigate and fix this problem for the betterment of the product? i'm not entirely sure if it's a vs or ie issue, but i think they would both be concerned by this. am willing to provide problem replication help if needed. thank you to everyone for you help.

Comment: who on earth would downvote this anyway? it actually is a beta 2 bug!!

Answer (score 0):

How is this method being called? It's possible you are mistakenly only calling the method with two parameters (javascript allows this, and the third parameter would just be undefined within the method body). Or it's possible you really are passing in an undefined value and not realizing it.

Ah you just edited the question. In that case, check to see what $get(HiddenAgeID) is returning, it's probably returning null because it can't find it.

Comment: the method calling is also displayed in the question, here it is, its a number, string, string... : SubmitAge(24, 'ctl00_MainContent_arFrom_upAgeRange', 'MainContent_arFrom_HiddenAge');

Comment: Have you tried this in a different browser? If this is failing in IE but works in Firefox, for example, that might be good info.

Comment: haha, well guess what? it works PERFECTLY in Firefox, as it _should_ in ie!!! unbelievable... how should i move forward with this?

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account any possible ID munging due to naming containers, is `MainContent_arFrom_HiddenAge` the correct id on the client for the `HiddenAgeID`?

Looking at the ID of the UpdatePanel, is the id of HiddenAge supposed to be `ctl00_MainContent_arFrom_HiddenAge`?

Comment: the funny this is there ids are generated on the server side using upUpdatePanel.ClientID.ToString and hfHiddenAge.ClientID.ToString so they are correct, i also double checked this in the printed sources

Comment: the HiddenAgeID is just a string parameter to pass the name of the hidden field, which is namely 'MainContent_arFrom_HiddenAge'

i will try and let u know